# Не могу понять как организовать поиск и вывести результаты

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый утро, господа. Имеется небольшой внутренний сайт, на Semantic UI.


[image: Сайт]

Поиск организован с помощью стандартного модуля фреймворка

```
<div class="ui fluid search">
    <div class="ui fluid icon input">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя или фамилию для поиска...">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Поиск происходит в

```
var content = [{
          title: 'Туршиев Николай Манолисович : 1301',
          description: 'Кабинет: 209, инженер АСУП'
            },
            {
          title: 'Ханычев Алексей Владимирович : 1194',
          description: 'Кабинет: 209, монтажник связи-кабельщик'
            },
            {
          title: 'Бондарцова Людмила Сергеевна : 1194',
          description: 'Кабинет: 209, инженер по АСУП (Электронный документооборот)'
            }
        ];
```

**Просматривая фреймворк, я обнаружил интересную штуку - карточки. Идея в том, чтобы вывести список всех номеров(порядка 300 номеров) в виде карточек при загрузке страницы, после пользователь вводит имя сотрудника, все карточки убираются кроме нужной.**

Ребята я не прошу готового решения, если кто-то имеет какую-то информацию или видел похожий пример, укажите в каком направлении копать.

Заранее спасибо за ваши мысли и идеи!

Полный код страницы:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Телефонная книга</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="ui header center aligned">Телефонный справочник<sup><small>alpha</small></sup></h1>
    <h3 class="ui header center aligned">Служебных телефонов административно-<br>управленческого персонала ФГБУ СКФНКЦ ФМБА<br> России, Мед. центра «Юность» (ФФГБУ СКФНКЦ<br> ФМБА России в г. Ессентуки) и ОСМ Мед. центра<br> «Юность» в г. Кисловодске.<br> (по состоянию на 18.07.2017)
        </h3>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="sixteen wide column">
                    <div class="ui fluid search">
                        <div class="ui fluid icon input">
                            <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя или фамилию для поиска...">
                            <i class="search icon"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="results"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var content = [{
                title: 'Туршиев Николай Манолисович : 1301',
                description: 'Кабинет: 209, инженер АСУП'
            },
            {
                title: 'Ханычев Алексей Владимирович : 1194',
                description: 'Кабинет: 209, монтажник связи-кабельщик'
            },
            {
                title: 'Бондарцова Людмила Сергеевна : 1194',
                description: 'Кабинет: 209, инженер по АСУП (Электронный документооборот)'
            }
        ];
        $('.ui.search').search({
            source: content
        });
        </script>
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="sixteen wide column">
                    <div class="ui cards">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="content">
                                <i class="address right floated card icon"></i>
                                <div class="header">Туршиев Николай Манолисович</div>
                                <div class="meta">Инженер АСУП</div>
                                <div class="description">НОМЕР:1301 КАБИНЕТ:209</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="content">
                                <i class="address right floated card icon"></i>
                                <div class="header">Бондарцова Людмила Сергеевна</div>
                                <div class="meta">инженер АСУП</div>
                                <div class="description">НОМЕР:1194 КАБИНЕТ:209</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: хотите на js такое ?

Comment: @Horchynskyi Доброе утро, хотелось бы, но php - тоже решение)

Comment: ааа я думал вам именно с поиском помощь нужна)

Comment: @Horchynskyi, вы все правильно поняли, именно с поиском.

Comment: можете плжалйста конкретнеё описать что именно нужно

Comment: ну тогда надобудет считывать значение ввода в цылке по масиву объектов и проверять на объект имени, после выводить новый масив в html

Comment: @Horchynskyi, конечно. Из массива циклом вывести карточки на экран, поиском сортировать карточки на экране, по вводу пользователя.

Comment: понял, 5 минут)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Телефонная книга</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="ui header center aligned">Телефонный справочник<sup><small>alpha</small></sup></h1>
    <h3 class="ui header center aligned">Служебных телефонов административно-<br>управленческого персонала ФГБУ СКФНКЦ ФМБА<br> России, Мед. центра «Юность» (ФФГБУ СКФНКЦ<br> ФМБА России в г. Ессентуки) и ОСМ Мед. центра<br> «Юность» в г. Кисловодске.<br> (по состоянию на 18.07.2017)
        </h3>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="sixteen wide column">
                    <div class="ui fluid search">
                        <div class="ui fluid icon input">
                            <input id="search" class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя или фамилию для поиска...">
                            <button type="button" class="search icon" onclick="searchFunction()">Найти</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="results"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="sixteen wide column">
                    <div class="ui cards" id="cardsWrapper">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        //Массив
    var content = [{
            title: 'Туршиев Николай Манолисович : 1301',
            who: 'инженер АСУП',
            description: 'Кабинет: 209'
        },
        {
            title: 'Ханычев Алексей Владимирович : 1194',
            who: 'монтажник связи-кабельщик',
            description: 'Кабинет: 211'
        },
        {
            title: 'Бондарцова Людмила Сергеевна : 1194',
            who: 'инженер по АСУП (Электронный документооборот)',
            description: 'Кабинет: 210'
       }];
        //При загрузке станицы выводим все номера
        displayNumbers(content);
        //Наша функция по отображению номеров(принимает нужный масив полный или по поиску)
        function displayNumbers(array){
            //Очищаем старый запрос
            cardsWrapper.innerHTML = '';
            for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                //Здесь в цыкле создаются блоки и заполняются в cardsWrapper
                var newDivCard = document.createElement('DIV');
                newDivCard.classList.add("card");
                newDivCard.innerHTML = `<div class="content">
                                        <i class="address right floated card icon"></i>
                                        <div class="header">`+array[i].title+`</div>
                                        <div class="meta">`+array[i].who+`</div>
                                        <div class="description">`+array[i].description+`</div>
                                        </div>`
                cardsWrapper.appendChild(newDivCard);
            }
        }
        //Функция по поиску которая создает массив по поиску
    function searchFunction(){
        if(!search.value) displayNumbers(content);
        var newArrayCards = [];
        for(var i = 0;i<content.length;i++){
            var title = content[i].title.toLowerCase(), //toLowerCase - опускает всю строку в нижний регистр
                who = content[i].who.toLowerCase(), //так мы перестаем от него зависеть
                description = content[i].description.toLocaleLowerCase(),
                searchWord = search.value.toLowerCase();
            //Проходим по всем ключам объекта
            //Если символ или строка находитеся где-то в content.title добавляем в новый масив
            if(title.indexOf(searchWord) != -1 || who.indexOf(searchWord) != -1 || description.indexOf(searchWord) != -1){
                newArrayCards.push(content[i]);
            }
        }
        //Запускаем функцию отображения с новым масивом
        displayNumbers(newArrayCards);
    };
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Использовал ID чтобы легче было ориентироваться(сразу запускать в скрипте нужные операции на этих элементах)

search - принимает input
cardsWrapper - основной блок где отображаются телефоны

Чтобы обратно вывести все номера - оставляем пустую строку и жмем найти

Comment: Круто!!! Спасибо, а можете посоветовать, что почитать, чтоб достичь вашего уровня?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ 2 части и такой уровень будет)

Comment: Скажите, а можно ли улучшить поиск до полнотекстового и независимого от регистра?

Comment: Полнотекстового в лпане чтобы по всем полям проверялся, а не только по имени?

Comment: Именно. Просто человек, может не знать имени, может знать должность или кабинет. И еще скажите как я вас могу отблагодарить?

Comment: уже) отметили ответ)
сейчас добавлю в ответ

Comment: смотрите в функцию поиска

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Могу ли я указать внизу странички, что вы принимали участие в разработке?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62572/discussion-between-bobo-and-horchynskyi).